# vba select slicer item excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've recently discovered VBA code to filter slicers based off of variable names. It is a great tool for filtering what you want to see

The next step in my code is to potentially REMOVE visible data from my pivot table/chart (automatically).

Lets say I already have a variable "Remove_ITEM" that needs to be removed from the data shown. Remove_item is inside slicer ("slicer_Order").

The data is also inside a data model.

The code below is to ONLY show REmove_Item:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Order").'VisibleSlicerItemsList = ("[Actuals_Table].[Order].&["& Remove_item &"]")
```

Now i want to do the opposite

Comment: What about `ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Order").SlicerItems(Remove_Item).Selected=False`?

Comment: That gives me Run-Time error ' 1004':

Comment: And `Slicers("Slicer_Order").SlicerItems(Remove_Item).Selected=Fa‌​lse`? Did you set the value of `Remove_Item` with something in the possible values (ie `Remove_Item = "StringToRemove")`

Comment: for simplicity to check your code i replaced remove_item with the actual value i wanted removed. ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Order").SlicerItems("[Actuals_Table].[Order].&[000010961612]").Selected = False

Comment: to also check you code i made a different example. I made a table, 1 column letters, and 1 column numbers. I made slicers for each column. I tried your code ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Letter").SlicerItems("c").Selected = False  .  I was given run-time error '5'. invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: i'll just create an array and do the opposite. >  (show all items in slicer as array) > (remove items i don't want to see from the array) > (create loop to show only items in the array)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you are trying to achieve in your post.

Try the code below and let me know if it works as you intended:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SlicersTst()

Dim WB                      As Workbook
Dim OrderSlcrCache          As SlicerCache
Dim OrderSlcItem            As SlicerItem
Dim RemoveItem              As Variant

Set WB = ThisWorkbook

Set OrderSlcrCache = WB.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Order") '<-- set Slicer Cache to "Order" slicer
OrderSlcrCache.ClearManualFilter '<-- clear manual filters

RemoveItem = "c" '<-- set value for test

' loop through all slicer items in slicer "Order"
For Each OrderSlcItem In OrderSlcrCache.SlicerItems
    If OrderSlcItem.Name = RemoveItem Then OrderSlcItem.Selected = False
Next OrderSlcItem

End Sub
```

Comment: I had trouble with OrderSlcItem, but i made some breakthroughs. If i made the items i want to select into an array (and made sure it had the proper defiinition around it due to the data model. i get this :                Dim Arr() As String
ReDim Arr(1 To 2)

Arr(1) = "[Actuals_Table].[Order].&[000010840921]"
Arr(2) = "[Actuals_Table].[Order].&[000010949159]"

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_order").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Arr()

 Filtering by the array works great!

Comment: so now it's working for you ? can you add a screen-shot of your pivot and slice t your post ? I want to know want this code (which is working for me) is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind this is specifically for data model usage with a connection.

```
Sub Variables()
Part_Number = Worksheets("Solumina_Data_Page").Cells(Row, "B").Value
End Sub


Sub Sort_Part_Number()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Page1 = ActiveSheet.Name
Call Variables


Sheets("Dashboard").Activate

    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Material").VisibleSlicerItemsList = "[Part List].[Material].&[" & Part_Number & "]"
'    "[Part List].[Material].&[77C726210G1]" <<What we want to see

Sheets(Page1).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Heres a similar example using the array

```
Sub Use_ARRAY()


Dim ARR() As String
ReDim ARR(1 To 2)
Call Array_Actuals_Data 'get data
Call Array_Outliers_removed 'sort data

ARR(1) = "[Actuals_Table].[Order].&[000010840921]"
ARR(2) = "[Actuals_Table].[Order].&[000010949159]"

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_order").VisibleSlicerItemsList = ARR()

End Sub
```